# how to convert str to int

Tags: python, lexicographic

I'm making a guessing game and i need to know how to stop it from putting my answers in lexicographical order as that makes a bug in my game.

I've tried instead of having `elif Guess < str(value):` making it `elif Guess < int(value):` but i get the error message "'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'" and i'm having no luck with anything else

Here is the code im working with

```py
from random import *
from random import randint
import os

numbers = []
Guesses = []
dif = []

os.system('CLS')
print("I want you to guess my number")
print("\n \n \n \nIf you give up type 'give up' word for word")

f = open("Data.txt", "a")

print("Say 'yes' If You're Ready")

YN = input()



if YN == "yes":
    os.system('cls')
    print("Select a difficulty")
    print('impossible 1 - 10000')
    print('annoying 1 - 1000')
    print('hard 1 - 500')
    print('medium 1 - 200')
    print('easy 1 - 99')
    print('beginner 1 - 10')

diff = input()





if diff == 'easy':
    os.system('CLS')
    value = randint(1, 99)
    numbers.append(value)
    dif.append(diff)

elif diff == 'beginner':
    os.system('CLS')
    value = randint(1, 10)
    numbers.append(value)
    dif.append(diff)

elif diff == 'medium':
    os.system('CLS')
    value = randint(1, 199)
    numbers.append(value)
    dif.append(diff)

elif diff == 'hard':
    os.system('CLS')
    value = randint(1, 499)
    numbers.append(value)
    dif.append(diff)

elif diff == 'annoying':
    os.system('CLS')
    value = randint(1, 1000)
    numbers.append(value)
    dif.append(diff)

elif diff == 'impossible':
    os.system('CLS')
    value = randint(1, 10000)
    numbers.append(value)
    dif.append(diff)


os.system('cls')

while True:
    Guess = input()



    if Guess == "give up":
        print("The Number Was " + str(numbers))
        f.write("------------------------------------------------------------- \n \r")
        f.write("Guesses " + str(Guesses) + "\n \r")
        f.write("Difficulty: " + str(dif) + "\n \r")
        f.write("[USER GAVE UP] \n \r")
        f.write("Correct Answer: " + str(numbers) + "\n \r")
        f.write("------------------------------------------------------------- \n \r")
        break

    elif Guess < str(value):
        print("Higher")
        Guesses.append(Guess + " - Higher")

    elif Guess > str(value):
        print("Lower")
        Guesses.append(Guess + " - Lower")


    elif Guess == str(value):
        os.system('CLS')
        length = len(Guesses)
        f.write("------------------------------------------------------------- \n \r")
        f.write("Guesses " + str(Guesses) + "\n \r")
        f.write("Difficulty: " + str(dif) + "\n \r")
        f.write("Number Of Guesses [" + str(length) + "]\n \r")
        f.write("Correct Answer: " + str(numbers) + "\n \r")
        f.write("------------------------------------------------------------- \n \r")
        print("That Was Correct!")
        for x in Guesses:
            print(x)
        break

input()
```

Comment: You _must_ provide the full traceback...

Comment: ...and reduce the code to the minimal amount that is needed to show your problem.

Comment: Use `elif int(Guess) < int(value)` for numerical comparisons

Comment: Did you try comparing (int)Guess and (int)value? In this case you will have to take care of the scenario where Guess is neither "give up" nor a valid integer.

Comment: Is converting both to int an option? Otherwise, comparison operators won't work I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to convert Guess from str to int, and compare in integer.

```
elif int(Guess) < value:
```

Answer (score 0):

As maruchen notes you should be casting the Guess variable and not the value variable.

However, that alone is still going to leave you with problems. The user isn't forced to enter an integer and indeed string answers such as "give up" are expected. If you try an cast a string to an integer and the string contains non-numerics, then you will be faced with a ValueError. So best is to define a function like this:

```
def guess_less_than_value(guess, value):
    try:
        return int(guess) < int(value)
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Then you can but in the body of your code:

```
if guess_less_than_value(Guess, value):
    ....
```

And likewise with greater than.